# NodeJS: ESLint Rule to Force "Correct" Import Names

Tags: node.js, module, eslint, commonjs

In a NodeJS, if a module exports a symbol with one name

```
// File: module-a.js
class Foo {}
module.exports = Foo
```

it's possible, and common, for that export to imported with a different name

```
// file: module-b.js
const Baz = require('./module-a')
```

Is there an ESLint rule that can flag exported classes and constructor functions that are imported with variable names different from their actual symbol name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this rule is not yet there in ESLint, but there's a PR open for this [Add rule to enforce default import naming](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/pull/1143) in [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import)

If you need it very badly you could add the rule manually into your project as a custom rule.